# How could I optimise this PHP function?

Tags: php, function, optimization, multidimensional-array, formatting

Here I have a function where I delete some keys from a nested array.
How could I optimise it in order to look prettier and maybe more efficiently?

$data is array type and contains the following:

```
$data = [
  '0' => [
     'key1' => 'value1',
     'key2' => 'value2',
     'key3' => 'value3'
  ],
  '1' => [
     'key1' => 'value4',
     'key2' => 'value5',
     'key3' => 'value6'
  ],
];
```

And $column(s) is of type array and contains keys that I want to remove from this array of arrays

```
$columns = ['key1', 'key2'];
```

And a part of the function written in PHP is:

```
***
        $newData = [];

        foreach ($data as $row) {
           $newRow = array_diff_key($row,array_flip($columns));
           array_push($newData, $newRow);
        }

        return $newData;
***
```

Expected result:

```
$data = [
  '0' => [
     'key1' => 'value1'
  ],
  '1' => [
     'key1' => 'value4'
  ],
];
```

The function works well but it looks awful :D

Comment: Optimization questions might be better off on https://codereview.stackexchange.com, but be sure to take their [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and go through their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) first

Comment: You can't have two `0` keys in the same array. Array keys must be unique.

Comment: You could flip the `$columns` array only once outside the loop

Comment: You could replace `array_push($newData, $newRow);` with `$newData[] = $newRow;` and then the overhead of calling a function would be removed

Comment: Come to that Why are you flipping the array you hard code?

Comment: This is just an example, I have a lot bigger data then that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem

```
function delKey ($data, $columns){
    $result = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i<count($data); $i++){
        $a = $data["$i"];
        foreach ($columns as $key){
            if (isset($a[$key])){
                unset($a[$key]);
            }
        }
        $result["$i"] = $a;
    }
    return $result;
}
```